# Trigger Functions for Firebase does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I want to fetch data from external url through trigger using Firebase cloud functions. However, fetch data and update specific node not work.

What is wrong? My Firebase plan is Blaze.

**function error** : [print screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBJT8.png)

**database error** : [print screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJyv.png)

**External Data Structure - JSON**

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "details_a": "15+ Heavy duty truck comprising of T800 ...",
      "equipment_id": "ChIJW6AIkVXemwARTtIvZ2xC3FA"
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const request = require('request');
exports.setDetails = functions.database.ref('/equipment/{pushId}').onWrite((event) => {
    if (event.data.previous.exists()) { return }
    if (!event.data.exists()) { return }    
    const post = event.data.val();
    if (post.details){ return };
    const number = post.number;
    const details = '';
    request.get({
        uri: 'https://api.domain.com/json?partnumber=' + number,
        json: true,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type'   : 'application/json' ,
        }
    }, (error, response) => {
        if (error) { 
            console.error(error);
        } else { 
            details = response.results[0].details_a;
            console.log('Response: ', response.headers);
            res.status(200).end('OK');
        }
    });
    return admin.database().ref('/equipment/{pushId}').update({number: number, details: details});
});
```

Comment: Since it's complaining about the `results` field being `undefined`, it might be useful to log the entire response and see what's going on.

Comment: Please don't show pictures of errors and code in a question.  It's far better to copy the text and paste it into a code block in the question so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.get()` is asynchronous, meaning that function returns before the results are available.  The callback you provided will be invoked some time later with the results.  Since the function returns immediately, that means the last line of your function (the `return` statement) will execute before the callback is invoked.  Try putting log statements into each part of your code to see the order things are actually invoked.

Since you're calling the Firebase `update` method immediately after `request.get()`, but before its results are available, that means `details` contains an empty string every time.  That's definitely not what you want.

Instead, you should update the database only after the fetch finishes.  To make it easier, you might want to look into using the request-promise module to make a request that returns a promise that contains results, then chaining a `then()` method off of that to perform the update.

You still have to return a promise that's resolved only after *all* the async work is complete in your function.

One more problem.  This line of code doesn't seem to do anything:

```
res.status(200).end('OK');
```

That looks like something you'd use in an HTTP trigger to send the results to the client. But you're writing a database trigger here.  I'd expect this line of code to fail since `res` is never defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: I have proceeded as you suggested. This is the result `TypeError: request.get(...).then is not a function`

Comment: other result: `Response:  { 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  date: 'Tue, 06 Mar 2018 04:04:34 GMT',
  expires: 'Wed, 07 Mar 2018 04:04:34 GMT',
  'cache-control': 'public, max-age=86400',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  server: 'mafe',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'alt-svc': 'hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"',
  'accept-ranges': 'none',
  vary: 'Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding',
  connection: 'close' }`

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this problem and I noticed that I was making reference to realtime database instead of Firestore. When I correct this, every thing started to work properly.

```
exports.onActionsWrite = functions.firestore
    .document('/actions/{id}')
    .onWrite(event => {
        console.log('I'm here!');
        // Do something...
        return null;
    });
```

You also can take a look at firestore documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events